# centring h4 title for lower screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with 2 centred columns. Everything looks fine on a normal screen size, although when I test it on a smaller screen like a mobile, the columns are not fully centred. Can anyone tell me why?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <br />
        <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Organisation Booking Details</strong></h4>
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
            Col1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Col2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="row" style="margin-left:4px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4" >
       Col3
    </div>
</div>
```

Normal size screen looks fine:

[image]

Smaller screen (columns are not centred properly):

[image]

Comment: the h4 title looks centered to me.  if you want the form centered you'll have to specify a width and use margin: auto or use flexbox.  see here https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @Deryck thanks for the reply. you are correct about the title. could you give me a quick example of using width and margin to fix the columns please?

Comment: add a class to that wrapper element (holding the form) and then (you would have to do this in a CSS block somewhere - separate CSS file, a `<style>`, etc.) add `@media ( max-width: 959px ) { .WRAPPER-ELEMENT-CLASS { width: 100%; max-width: 800px; margin: auto; } }`.  Of course adjust as you see fit

Comment: However, this may not look the way you are hoping based on the rest of the styles.  Like if the inputs are styled to the left and have a width < 100%, it will still appear offset poorly.  you have to go through and troubleshoot and adjust as you find things

Comment: Thanks a lot Deryck! My front end skills are poor but I will give it a go